# Asynchronous Requests before rendering Page in Express.JS

Tags: javascript, express, async-await

I'm trying to implement a Sequence of HTTP-Requests for training purposes in express.js. In order to do that i worked with async/await to wait for my requests and wrapped them in a try catch block. Everything works as aspected, since i added some console.log to check the flow. When everything is done, i want to render my page with the built in res.render() function but it throws an error when calling res.render()[res.render is not a function].

I could load the data via AJAX but is this really necessary?

```
/* Express Functions */
router
.get('/', async function (res,req,next){
    try{
        doSynchronousThings();
        const ParticipantIds = await xingRequests.getParticipantIds();
        console.log('...getParticipantIds response:');
        console.log(ParticipantIds);
        finalLog();
        const ParticipantData = await xingRequests.getParticipantData(ParticipantIds[0]);
        console.log('...getParticipantData response:');
        console.log(ParticipantData);
        console.log('...all done');
    }catch(err){
        console.error(err);
        next(err);
    }
    res.render('test', {
        page: {
            title:'Xing Event API',
            message: 'Happy Hacking!'
        }
    });
});
```

The xingRequest methods just fire a request-promise based request and return the response objects.

Comment: Make sure you configured your template engine, `app.set('view engine', 'pug');`

Comment: Arguments order is wrong. Should be `function (req, res, next)`.